# For and If in Awk scripts (bash)

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop, awk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My bash command is

```
awk -f code.txt input.txt
```

This is my code

```
{z=0
for(i=2;i<17;i++)
    if ($i=="y")
        z++
print $1 " " z}
```

This is my input

```
AaA y n y n y n n n y n n n n n y
BbB n y y n n n n n n n n n n n n
```

My output should be

```
AaA 5
BbB 2
```

Yet it is

```
AaA 4
BbB 2
```

After messing around with the code, it seems it doesn't register the last symbol of a line.

```
{z=0
for(i=2;i<18;i++)
        print $i
print $1 " " z}
```

When I run this it outputs all y/n, so the problem must be somewhere in the if-statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be the case that your input file has MS-DOS line endings (CRLF). The last symbol will be read as `y<CR>`. To check whether this is true, on a Linux system you can run

```
hexdump -C input.txt
```

Comment: That's my hexdump:

`00000000  41 61 41 20 79 20 6e 20  79 20 6e 20 79 20 6e 20  |AaA y n y n y n |

00000010  6e 20 6e 20 79 20 6e 20  6e 20 6e 20 6e 20 6e 20  |n n y n n n n n |
00000020  79 0d 0a 42 62 42 20 6e  20 79 20 79 20 6e 20 6e  |y..BbB n y y n n|
00000030  20 6e 20 6e 20 6e 20 6e  20 6e 20 6e 20 6e 20 6e  | n n n n n n n n|
*
00000044`

Comment: If you paste the hexdump into the question and format it as code, it will be easier to read.

Comment: `0d 0a` is the problem, there should be only `0a`. Use `dos2unix input.txt` and try again your awk script.

Comment: That was it! Thank you both Alex for the info and Cyrus for the command! I'm on Windows10Bash so that caused my MSDOS formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be in `CRLF`. You can fix that in an awk loop with

```
sub(/\r/,"",$NF)
```

ie. by removing `CR` (replacing with nothing) from the last field. Also, you could use that `sub` or `gsub` for counting the `y` occurrences:

```
$ awk '$0=$1 OFS gsub(FS "y","&")' file
AaA 5
BbB 2
```

This way the `\r` does not matter as we just replace `y` with itself (`&`).